# Custom search engine help - Google

Tags: javascript, google-custom-search

I'm experiencing issues with the custom search engine API. Essentially, I'm trying to create a tool that verifies if specific URLs are indexed. Although it's somewhat functional, there are hiccups.

When I use the site search feature within the custom search engine, it returns no results. However, performing the same search on Google directly shows the URL is indeed indexed. I've reviewed the settings and attempted various solutions, but the problem persists.

For instance:

- In the custom search engine, searching for "site:[https://www.rackbuddy.dk/pages/sovevaerelse"](https://www.rackbuddy.dk/pages/sovevaerelse%22) gives no results, even though I've confirmed the URL is indexed via the Google search console.
- In contrast, doing the same search on Google directly provides the expected results.

I'm quite puzzled by this. Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.